# Ending Group Calls in Callkit

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I am working on a VoIP app. I have integrated the callkit framework but having some trouble with Group calls.

The situation is the following:

1. Made a call.
2. Put first call on hold and made another.
3. Clicked Merge button to merge both calls. Called CXSetGroupCallAction to merge both calls. It is successfully done.
4. Now while ending the conference call, I am trying to end both the ongoing calls reported to callkit as the user pressed EndCall button.
5. Created separate CXEndCallAction for both calls and executed the transaction. End call transaction is successful for both but callkit keeps on showing the red banner at the top.

What may be the reason? Is there a different procedure to follow to end a CXGroupCall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red banner means AVAudioSession is still active. Use CallKit's provider method to deactivate your audio engine

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
```

Comment: Yes.. I was having an active RTC Connection in the background which is why Red Banner was visible even though call was ended. Thanks for your response.

Comment: No problem, I had the same issue :)